# STM32 - Read I/O from multiple Tasks

Tags: c, stm32, freertos

I'm using FreeRTOS in my STM32F4 based board, and I read about the communication between tasks with queues and semaphores, easy to understand and apply.

But on the documentation, I don't find any information about if is secure to call the same method from different task, for example:

```
void DefaultTask(void const * argument)
{
    uint8_t pin = 10;
    uint16_t analog = ADC_GetAnalog(pin);
    uint32_t encoder =  Encoder_GetCount(1);
}

void SecondTask(void const * argument)
{
    uint8_t pin = 14;
    uint16_t analog = ADC_GetAnalog(pin);
    uint32_t encoder =  Encoder_GetCount(2);
}
```

The ADC_GetAnalog:

```
uint16_t ADC_GetAnalog(uint8_t PinNumber)
{
    if((PinNumber >=1)&&(PinNumber<=18))
    {
        return ADC_Pin[PinNumber].AnalogValue;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

I also have multiple encoders in my system (interrupts that increment/decrement the property CNT of the htim# ), and call the read method in the same line as the ADC, also from different Tasks:

```
uint32_t Encoder_GetCount(uint8_t encoder_num)
{
    volatile __IO uint32_t count = 0;
    switch(encoder_num)
    {
    case 1:
        count =  htim1.Instance->CNT;
        break;
    case 2:
        count =  htim3.Instance->CNT;
        break;
    case 3:
        count =  htim5.Instance->CNT;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return (uint32_t)count;
}
```

Today I use this way, but would like to know if it's the best (safer) way!!

Comment: The concept of reentrancy or thread-safety is a topic you can read up on, as you are essentially asking if a function is reentrant or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you provide, it appears your functions that can be called simultaneously are only reading stuff, not writing them. So you are good to go. Even if you were writing stuff, if it is local variables, it is fine (each task will have it own copy)

You will need to care about synchronization when you write global variables, or write stuff to certain peripherals (eg, a serial flash chip, you don't want 2 tasks to use it at the same time). One way to deal with it is simply with semaphores/mutexes, or preferably (if possible) have only 1 task with access to this peripheral, a clean design is key to a maintainable system.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what function does.

Your functions does not change any global variable so it should be safe to call them from different tasks.

For example, if you would had function which writes to global variable, eg. buffer, second call will overwrite changes made by first call. If buffer is used to send data both task could (depends on timing) send same bytes.

Comment: Great! I only read variables in those shared methods, I do have other methods that write on to it, but in this case I used a semaphore.